# How to query a C# dictionary and return a specific set of values

Tags: c#, linq, collections, lambda

I have a dictionary in my C# program that contains a list of Key + Values.

The values are `itemid, Month, Year, Count`

I would like to query the dictionary by comparing a set of values (`itemid, Month, Year`) and return true or false if a the specific `itemid + Month + Year` exist.

So if all 3 values (`itemid + Month + Year`) exist return true else return false.

I tried something like this

```
(if (myd.Select(d => d.Value.itemid == item.itemid && d.Value.Month == DateRange.Month  && d.Value.Year == DateRange.Year).ToString() != "")
```

The above didn't work.

Comment: Try to loop thru the dictionary and compare the values adding them to another dictionary

Answer (score 3):

You seem to misunderstand the usage of the Select() method. Select creates a "projection"; given an input collection (enumerable) of elements, it produces an output enumerable that is equal in cardinality, but is composed of elements that are each the result of a transformation of the corresponding element of the input.

What you need is either a Where() method (which returns a list, lesser or equal in cardinality to the input, of the elements from the input for which a boolean condition is true), or an Any() method (which returns a single "true" or "false" if any of the elements in the input meet the condition):

```
if(myd.Where(d => d.Value.itemid == item.itemid 
                && d.Value.Month == DateRange.Month 
                && d.Value.Year == DateRange.Year).Count() >= 1)
   ...

//produces the equivalent result but generally performs faster
if(myd.Any(d => d.Value.itemid == item.itemid 
                && d.Value.Month == DateRange.Month 
                && d.Value.Year == DateRange.Year))
   ...
```

Comment: Combination of where and count is not efficient, Also is not good.

Comment: ... which I stated in the comment in the code. Whether he uses Where or Any depends on exactly what result he needs; Where()'s result is an enumerable that can be further processed, while Any() produces a concrete result. I gave him both so he could see that both methods take the lambda he'd tried to use with Select and produce the correct answer.

Comment: The usage is obvious, it's within `if` condition, Also combination of where and count is not good anyway (except in linq2sql, still is redundant there) you can write: myList.Count(x=>f(x)), there is no need to use where (causing to one more iteration, per check totally 2n instead of n), Also as I said at first, it's not good (readability, efficiency, logically, technically, anything comes in mind).

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but I keep getting false when I use myd.Any. I can see from debugging my application that the item definetly exsist in the dictionary.

Comment: I think I have found the reason why I am getting all false. My dictionary seem to be adding spaces to the values. Example month = "4   " year = "2011   "

Answer (score 1):

If like linq-Syntax, this checks if at least one item that satisfies all three condition exists:

```
if((from d in myd
where d.Value.itemid == item.itemid
&& d.Value.Month == DateRange.Month
&& d.Value.Year == DateRange.Year).FirstOrDefault() != null)
```

Comment: You can simply write: myList.FirstOrDefault(x=>f(x)), in fact you can use where conditional function in FirstOrDefault.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a 2nd dictionary if you want to do lookups with another key (in this case itemid,month,year, probably placed into a Tuple), and you'll need to maintain them both whenever you add/remove from either.

Answer (score 0):

use Where to filter (I'm assuming the condition in your code is defined correctly... you haven't given us enough info to evaluate that)

```
var filteredDictionary = myd.Where(d => d.Value.itemid == item.itemid && d.Value.Month == DateRange.Month  && d.Value.Year == DateRange.Year)
```

use Select to transform from a KeyValuePair to just a value

```
var filteredValues = filteredDictionary.Select(x=>x.Value)
```

use Any to return a bool of whether or not an item exists

```
bool matchExists = myd.Any(d => d.Value.itemid == item.itemid && d.Value.Month == DateRange.Month  && d.Value.Year == DateRange.Year)
```

`Any` is going to be most efficient for the problem you describe because it will stop evaluating items in the dictionary and return True as soon as a match is found

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with .NET 4.0 you can use Tuples as keys.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<int,int,int>,MyValueType>();
```

You can then test if a value exists with

```
var key = new Tuple<int,int,int>(item.itemid, DateRange.Month, DateRange.Year);
if(dict.ContainsKey(key)) {
   ...
}
```

Or you can test

```
if(dict.ContainsValue(referenceValue)) {
    ...
}
```

You will have to pass it a reference value containing what you are looking for. Make sure that your value type implements `EqualityComparer<T>`.

The first method will be much faster, since the dictionary is accessed by the key. If you are not accessing the dictionary by the key, you could use a `List<T>` as well.